# Code coverage for AuraHandledException

Tags: code-coverage

Here's my simple scenario I am comparing custom Account_ID__c in 'Account' object and Seller_ID__c in Item_Deal__c object if there is a match it should insert a new record else it should through an error 'Invalid seller id' and everything is fine till here. Now my issue is I am unable to cover else part in my apex class, appreciate your help.

```java
public without sharing class Create_Item_Deal {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void saveRecord(Item_Deal__c itemd) {
        List<Account> results = [SELECT id FROM Account WHERE Account_ID__c = : itemd.Seller_ID__c];
        if (results.size() != 0) {
            itemd.Account__c = results.get(0).id;
            try {
                insert itemd;
            } catch(exception e) {
                system.debug('-------getMessage-----------'+e.getMessage());
                system.debug('-------getLineNumber--------'+e.getLineNumber());
            }
        } else {
            AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException(itemd.Seller_ID__c + ' is not a valid Seller Account ID');
            e.setMessage(itemd.Seller_ID__c+'Invalid seller id');
            system.debug(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

TEST CLASS::

```java
@isTest
private class Create_Item_Deal_Test{

    static testmethod void test_saveRecord(){
        String sellerId = '1234';
        Account itdAct = new Account(
            Name = '123Cycles'
        );
        insert itdAct;

        Item_Deal__c itmd = new Item_Deal__c(
            Reg_price__c = 23211,Sale_Price__c = 39292,
            Hot_Deal_Price__c = 32432,
            Vertical__c = 'foo',
            Category__c = 'vert',
            Deal_Dates__c = 'July 31 to Aug 13 (Wk 27 & 28)'
        );
        itmd.Account__c = itdAct.Id;

        insert itmd;

        Create_Item_Deal.saveRecord(itmd);

        System.assertEquals(itmd.Seller_ID__c, itdAct.Account_ID__c, 'Valid Account ID');

        Test.startTest();
        try {
            insert itmd;
            Create_Item_Deal.saveRecord(itmd);
        } catch(AuraHandledException e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());           
            System.assert(e.getMessage().containsIgnoreCase('is not a valid Seller Account ID'));
            system.assert(false, e.getMessage());
            System.assertNotEquals(itmd.Seller_ID__c, itdAct.Account_ID__c, 'Invalid Account ID');
        }     
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the query you are looking for a Accounts by the custom field Account_ID__c with the value comming in the item in the field Seller_ID__c. If only no record is found you throw the exception.

As the account you are creating has null in that value and so does the item, you are always going to go inside the if condition and never throw an exception.

I would recommend you to first, edit the try-catch inside your Create_Item_Deal class, as you are omitting the errors at insertion.

And for the test, I would recommend you to split your test in more than one and try to test each case separetly... Like in this example. Where you have a test setup that creates all the necesarry data, and then a test method that tests the success, and a test method that tests the errors

```java
@isTest
private class Create_Item_Deal_Test {
    
    private static final String ACC_ID = 'SOMEID';
    
    @TestSetup
    static void makeData() {
        Account itdAct = new Account(
            Name = '123Cycles',
            Account_ID__c = ACC_ID
        );
        insert itdAct;
    }

    @isTest
    static testmethod void test_saveRecordSuccess(){
        Item_Deal__c itmd = new Item_Deal__c(
            Reg_price__c = 23211,
            Sale_Price__c = 39292,
            Hot_Deal_Price__c = 32432,
            Vertical__c = 'foo',
            Category__c = 'vert',
            Deal_Dates__c = 'July 31 to Aug 13 (Wk 27 & 28)',
            Seller_ID__c = ACC_ID
        );

        Test.startTest();
        Create_Item_Deal.saveRecord(itmd);
        Test.stopTest();
        
        System.assertNotEquals(null, itmd.Id, 'Expected to have created the id');
    }

    @isTest
    static void test_saveRecordNotFound(){
        Exception except;
        Item_Deal__c itmd = new Item_Deal__c(
            Reg_price__c = 23211,
            Sale_Price__c = 39292,
            Hot_Deal_Price__c = 32432,
            Vertical__c = 'foo',
            Category__c = 'vert',
            Deal_Dates__c = 'July 31 to Aug 13 (Wk 27 & 28)',
            Seller_ID__c = 'NON-EXISTING-ID'
        );

        Test.startTest();
            try {
                Create_Item_Deal.saveRecord(itmd);
            } catch(AuraHandledException e) {
                except = e;
            }
        Test.stopTest();
        
        System.assertNotEquals(null, e, 'Expected an exception to be thrown');
    }
}
```